# Can't open install.wim in System Image Manager because of invalid version

Tags: windows-10, adk

I am running Windows 10 Pro 64bit on my PC, and have installed Windows ADK for Windows 10. When using Windows System Image Manager, and trying to load a `install.wim` file in it, i get the following error message:

[image]

Which in the log looks something like this:

```
20:38 : This application requires version 10.0.10240.16384 of the Windows ADK.
Install this version to correct the problem
20:38 : 
20:38 : Error opening Windows image at D:\sources\install.wim.

20:38 : 
20:38 : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
   bij Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimFileHandle..ctor(String wimPath)
   bij Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimInfo..ctor(String wimPath)
   bij Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.Cpi.OpenWim(String wimPath)
   bij Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ImagePicker.GetImageInfoFromPath(String path)
   bij Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ImagePicker.ValidateImageFileOrFolder(String fileOrFolder)
```

After doing [some research](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3bb0f17-3e2c-4fdc-8217-40126e43ac2e/windows-system-image-manager-version-1001024016384-errors?forum=win10itprosetup), I found an answer to upgrade my ADK to the version that was asked for in the error message (16384).

I could download [this version here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a31d1dee-8f00-44c8-bf3f-e068d183b65e/windows-adk-for-windows-10-july-2015-now-available?forum=win10itprosetup).

When checking the version I currently have in SIM, I noticed I 10.0.10240.16384 version:

[image]

How do I load install.wim, from an Windows 10 installation disk, into SIM, without getting any errors?

Comment: See if [the answer here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3bb0f17-3e2c-4fdc-8217-40126e43ac2e/windows-system-image-manager-version-1001024016384-errors?forum=win10itprosetup) solves it for you

Comment: @Moab As described in my question, i did that, and the problem still occurs when trying to open the file with the right version of WIM.

Comment: Just testing per OP request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/answers-comments-only-show-up-as-notification-on-my-phone?noredirect=1#comment858504_263826).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution [here](http://deploymentresearch.com/Research/Post/399/How-to-REALLY-create-a-Windows-10-ISO-no-3rd-party-tools-needed).

Run the below script from Deployment Tools Environment

```
:: Rename the original install.wim file.
rename D:\sources\install.wim install.bak
:: Create an empty temporary directory.
mkdir D:\sources\dummy
:: Create a new install.wim file with dummy image.
dism.exe /Capture-Image /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim /CaptureDir:D:\sources\dummy /Name:dummy /Compress:Max
:: Export the first Windows image to the empty install.wim file.
dism.exe /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:D:\sources\install.bak /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim /Compress:Max
:: Delete the first dummy index in install.wim
dism.exe /Delete-Image /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim /Index:1
:: Delete temporary directory.
rmdir D:\sources\dummy
```

Now you can open install.wim in WSIM.

Also you can delete the original (install.bak) file and create the the bootable media using oscdimg.exe

Comment: This helped me when WSIM demanded the same version 10.0.14393.0 of the ADK that I was already using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 7Zip to extract install.esd to install.wim.

I had tried using the DISM cmd running cmd line as admin, but was also getting "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".  DISM log file was only marginally helpful and I decided to try 7ZIP, which seems to be working for me now.